# How do I add a tune from Windows Media Player to Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, windows-media-player

I have ripped to Windows Media Player, an album with 12 tunes on it.  It shows up fine in my WMP Library.  How do I put ONE of those tunes into DropBox?

Answer (score 2):

After ripping to Windows Media Player, the album should appear as a new directory inside your your "Music" directory.
You can copy/paste them to your Dropbox folder from there.